# Custom command session

Tags: php, batch-file, remote-access

Keeps saying input is "Echo is on Echo is off" when you type any command.
This is for a batch file on a remote drive that needs to read log files and
post files etc.
its something like this
set /p input= name:
run %input% (as a command)
ive tried making a temp batch file when I looked at it said echo is on echo is off.
[I keep getting this.[code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8htOk.png)
Echo is on
Echo is off
Echo is on
Echo is on
something like that it should just run the input
yes I know this is a security flaw but not many people would want to hack this.

Comment: Please don't link to pictures of your code. Paste your code as text into the question itself. That makes it much easier for us to help you. (Honestly: do you expect us to re-type your code to be able to help you with it?)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things wrong with the code you posted. First of all, you misspelled `%input%` on line 4 as `%inut%`. You're getting "echo is off" because undefined variables get parsed as nothing and `echo` by itself simply prints whether echo is on or off.

Secondly (and more importantly), don't put percent signs around the variable name when you're setting the variable; otherwise, you'll set a variable whose name is the value of the variable instead.

```
@echo off
:start
set /p "input=venom66 %date% %time%"
echo %input% >>tmp.bat
call tmp.bat
echo %input%
goto start
```

Comment: Sorry for not putting the code but thanks for making it work!!